# ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService returning null on load

Tags: android, android-connectivitymanager

I'm getting an error in `ConnectivityManager` when loading the app. I've used it a lot but this is the first time I've encounter it.

it says null but I don't have an idea what this error cause.

this is my code:

```
   final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if (wifi.isConnected()) {
                baseUrl = URL1;
            } else if (mobile.isConnected()) {
                baseUrl = URL2;
            }
```

and this is the error on `Logcat`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont see anything in that logcat screenshot that indicates connectivity manager is null

Comment: it points out on the  `final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Comment: I update the question. I attached a screenshot

Comment: Where are you using that code?

Comment: on `OnCreateView`

Comment: Try replace `getContext()` with `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @AbuYousuf , I'm using `Fragment v4`

Comment: try using `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` for Fragment

Comment: now it points a null on `.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: That second screen shot is not an error only a warning, your real issue is in `Conductor_Menu` on line `357` as shown in your first screen shot

Comment: @tyczj yep. it points out on the second screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`getContext()` may become null when your activity is killed or app goes to background. Since this may happen in runtime, use `try-catch`.

```
try {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Use this code--
and make sure that you context should not be null.

    enter code here
public static boolean checkConnectivity(Context context){
        boolean isConnected = false;
        try{
            ConnectivityManager connService = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo network = connService.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(network != null) {
                State state = network.getState();

                if(network.isConnected()){
                    isConnected = true;
                }
            }else{
                isConnected = false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isConnected;
    }
```